# Is this sentence correct? "So, I think that every country has its beauty, but your own one should be the first to explore."

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, sentence, sentence-patterns, complex-sentences

I meant to say that the first country you explore should be your own one.

Comment: "It's" can be changed to "its" for a start ;)

Comment: Thanks, but the thing I was concerned about is that it might mean that _'the country explores something'_, not that _I explore the country_...

Answer (score 2):

It's OK. But your explanation sentence is much better in terms of brevity and zest. "The first country you explore should be your own." That's a nice succinct thought.

To improve your original sentence, I would word it this way:
"I think that every country has its own beauty, but your own country is the first you should explore."